# How do I split Datatime in R?

Tags: r, datetime

I have a datetime attribute as shows below

```
    +----------------------+
    |       DateTime       |
    +----------------------+
    | 2016-01-01T00:00:00  |
    | 2016-01-01T00:20:00  |
    | 2016-01-01T00:40:00  |
    | 2016-01-01T01:00:00  |
    +----------------------+
```

and I am looking for a solution something like the below table,

```
    +------------+----------+
    |    Date    |   Time   |
    +------------+----------+
    | 2016-01-01 | 00:00:00 |
    | 2016-01-01 | 00:20:00 |
    | 2016-01-01 | 00:40:00 |
    | 2016-01-01 | 01:00:00 |
    +------------+----------+
```

I tried the below code,

```
    req_df$Date <- as.Date(req_df$DateTime) 
    req_df$Time <- format(as.POSIXct(req_df$DateTime) ,format = "%H:%M:%S")
```

It actually returns a table like below,

```
    +------------+----------+
    |    Date    |   Time   |
    +------------+----------+
    | 2016-01-01 | 00:00:00 |
    | 2016-01-01 | 00:00:00 |
    | 2016-01-01 | 00:00:00 |
    | 2016-01-01 | 00:00:00 |
    +------------+----------+
```

why is it that I get a table like above and what changes should I make in the code to get the output as mentioned?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the difference between the two outputs below

```
as.POSIXct('2016-01-01T00:20:00', tz = "UTC")
#[1] "2016-01-01 UTC"

as.POSIXct('2016-01-01T00:20:00', format = "%Y-%m-%dT%T", tz = "UTC")
#[1] "2016-01-01 00:20:00 UTC"
```

As the `DateTime` column is not in standard format, you need to explicitly mention the `format` in `as.POSIXct`.

Hence,

```
req_df$Time <- format(as.POSIXct(req_df$DateTime, format = "%Y-%m-%dT%T"), 
               format = "%T")
```

should give you what you expected output.